# VBScript that exports a chart as an image

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'd like to export an Excel chart as an image. I have the Excel application, workbook and worksheet objects set up (not sure I need all 3 but it's running smoothly so far). And I am generating the Chart and populating it fine as well. The only sticking point is really the export.

```
sub insert_array_into_excel_range(array)
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      objExcel.Visible = True
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("M:\VBScripts\MYcharts.xlsx", 0, False)
    Set objws = objworkbook.sheets("sheet1")
    array_length = UBound(array)
    set paste_recordset_toRange = objExcel.Range(objws.Cells(1,2),objws.Cells(array_length,2))
    paste_recordset_toRange.Value = objExcel.Transpose(array)

    Set oChart = objExcel.Charts
    oChart.Add()
    Set oMychart = oChart(1)
    oMyChart.Activate
    oMyChart.ChartType = 4
    oMyChart.SetSourceData paste_recordset_toRange
    oMyChart.Export "M:\VBScripts\", "myGIF.gif", "GIF"


end sub
```

error: 8003007B

Comment: Untested, but try `oMyChart.Export "M:\VBScripts\myGIF.gif", "GIF"`

Comment: Check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.export Parameters are `FileName`, `FilterName` and `Interactive`, but only the first one is mandatory.